# Is There an Easy Way to Retrieve Field's External Alias

Tags: apex, lightning-connect, describefieldresult

When creating custom fields on external objects you have the ability to add "External Alias / External Column Name" of the corresponding field name in the external data source.

[image]

I've got a situation where I need a way to find out the corresponding external column name based on the field API name (in APEX) in order to make things easier, though I couldn't find anything in the [DescribeFieldResult Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_fields_describe) nor had any luck with Workbench...

I thought about having a Custom Settings "Map", but that seems like an overkill for something that should be there out of the box.

Wondering whether I am missing something and/or if anyone has a better approach.

Comment: `externalDeveloperName` from [CustomField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_customfield.htm?search_text=External) metadata maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve this using the Tooling API by using the `externalDeveloperName` attribute of the `Metadata` returned from:
`/services/data/v39.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/[your field id]`

Alternatively, if you don't know the field ID you can use the query endpoint,the only issue with this is that if you want to return the `Metadata` field you must ensure that your query only returns a single result, so you'll probably want to filter on `TableEnumOrId` as well as the `DeveloperName` of your field:
`/services/data/v39.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+Metadata+FROM+CustomField+WHERE+DeveloperName=[your field API name]+AND+TableEnumOrId=[your table enum/id]`

Example response:

```
{
  "size" : 1,
  "totalSize" : 1,
  "done" : true,
  "queryLocator" : null,
  "entityTypeName" : "CustomField",
  "records" : [ {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "CustomField",
      "url" : "/services/data/v39.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N0Y00000ByqwZUAR"
    },
    "Metadata" : {
      "caseSensitive" : null,
      "customDataType" : null,
      "defaultValue" : null,
      "deleteConstraint" : null,
      "deprecated" : null,
      "description" : "icon",
      "displayFormat" : null,
      "displayLocationInDecimal" : null,
      "encrypted" : null,
      "escapeMarkup" : null,
      "externalDeveloperName" : "icon",
      "externalId" : false,
      "formula" : null,
      "formulaTreatBlanksAs" : null,
      "inlineHelpText" : null,
      "isConvertLeadDisabled" : null,
      "isFilteringDisabled" : false,
      "isNameField" : false,
      "isSortingDisabled" : false,
      "label" : "icon",
      "length" : 255,
      "lookupFilter" : null,
      "maskChar" : null,
      "maskType" : null,
      "metadataRelationshipControllingField" : null,
      "populateExistingRows" : null,
      "precision" : null,
      "readOnlyProxy" : null,
      "referenceTargetField" : null,
      "referenceTo" : null,
      "relationshipLabel" : null,
      "relationshipName" : null,
      "relationshipOrder" : null,
      "reparentableMasterDetail" : null,
      "required" : false,
      "restrictedAdminField" : null,
      "scale" : null,
      "startingNumber" : null,
      "stripMarkup" : null,
      "summarizedField" : null,
      "summaryFilterItems" : null,
      "summaryForeignKey" : null,
      "summaryOperation" : null,
      "trackFeedHistory" : null,
      "trackHistory" : null,
      "trackTrending" : null,
      "type" : "Text",
      "unique" : false,
      "urls" : null,
      "valueSet" : null,
      "visibleLines" : null,
      "writeRequiresMasterRead" : null
    }
  } ]
}
```